# Query to search for a MAX value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the MAX value from my column that is created as percentage and will get from a `nvarchar` column the information from different things.

This is the query:

```
SELECT Filetype AS 'Extensão', 
COUNT(*) AS 'Nº de ficheiros',
CAST(((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS 'Percentagem (%)',
SUM(Filesize) AS 'Total(KB)',
NULL AS 'Convertido para MB'
FROM infofile  
GROUP BY Filetype
UNION ALL
SELECT '---------------',
COUNT('Nº de extensões'),
((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile)), 
SUM(Filesize),
SUM(Filesize) / 1024 
FROM infofile
```

What I am trying to do is a query that gives me the MAX and MIN percentage from this column. I've tried to use

```
SELECT MAX('Percentagem (%)') * 100 
FROM infofile
```

but it will gives me an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Percentagem (%)' to data type int.

By the way this is a local database which is used on SqlServer

Comment: Why do you cast to decimal? Isn't the result of your calculation already a decimal?

Comment: If you want more help then show the complete query and tag your DBMS.

Comment: This is the query that I want. I want to get this

Comment: I understand what the part before `UNION ALL` does. (As mentioned, you should change single quotes to `[` and `]` though.) But what is the part after `UNION ALL` supposed to do? `COUNT('Nº de extensões')` equals `COUNT(*)`. `((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile))` is always `100`.

Comment: And where do you want to select min and max of the percentage? As two more columns after `[Convertido para MB]`? Or do you want to write a separate query based on this one? Or what else?

Comment: I will explain you man. Well, that lines after UNION ALL give me the result 's of what I've done before the UNION ALL

Comment: I want to insert it after 'Convertido para MB'. Sorry for that but I am Portuguese ahahah

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT --MAX('Percentagem (%)') 'Percentagem (%)' will be treated as a string. use [] to enclose the calculated column name
MAX([Percentagem (%)]),MIN([Percentagem (%)]) 
FROM infofile
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query fails, because 'Percentagem (%)' is a string starting with a 'P' followed by an 'e' and so on.

For column aliases use the standard SQL delimiter `"`: `MAX("Percentagem (%)")`. If you are on SQL Server use the non-standard delimiters `[` and `]` instead: `MAX([Percentagem (%)])`.

And the best solution would of course be not to use column or alias names that must be escaped in the first place, e.g. `MAX(percentagem)`.

Comment: I am using the Visual Studio 2015 interface....I want to make this query separated but I cant do that because "Percentagem (%)" isnt a real column you know?

Comment: Well, no, not really. As mentioned in the main comments: edit your questsion and show the complete SQL. (You've only shown one line starting with `CAST`, but you should show the complete query including `FROM` and `WHERE`). My second request was that you tag the DBMS you are using, which you haven't done either. Do you work in MySQL or SQL Server, on PostgreSQL or Oracle, or what else?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your SQL Server version is not too old, you can use window functions:

```
select 
  filetype as [Extensão], 
  count(*) as [Nº de ficheiros],
  count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as [Percentagem (%)],
  sum(filesize) as [Total(KB)],
  sum(filesize) / 1024.0 as [Convertido para MB],
  min(count(*)) over () * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as [Min. Percentagem (%)],
  max(count(*)) over () * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as [Max. Percentagem (%)]
from infofile  
group by filetype
order by filetype;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e0792/1

As to the totals line, it should be possible to generate that elegantly with `ROLLUP` or `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`, but I am not sure how these go along with the window functions. So I cannot give good advice here.

Sometimes it's easiest to get a totals line outside SQL in your app using a programming language.

Here is a working complete query:

```
select
  [Extensão], 
  sum([Nº de ficheiros]) as [Nº de ficheiros],
  round(sum([Percentagem (%)]), 2) as [Percentagem (%)],
  sum([Total(KB)]) as [Total(KB)],
  round(sum([Convertido para MB]),2) as [Convertido para MB],
  round(min([Min. Percentagem (%)]), 2) as [Min. Percentagem (%)],
  round(max([Max. Percentagem (%)]), 2) as [Max. Percentagem (%)]
from
(
  select 
    filetype as [Extensão], 
    count(*) as [Nº de ficheiros],
    count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as [Percentagem (%)],
    sum(filesize) as [Total(KB)],
    sum(filesize) / 1024.0 as [Convertido para MB],
    min(count(*)) over () * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as [Min. Percentagem (%)],
    max(count(*)) over () * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as [Max. Percentagem (%)]
  from infofile  
  group by filetype
) per_filetype
group by rollup([Extensão])
order by case when [Extensão] is null then 2 else 1 end, [Extensão];
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e0792/29

Comment: The problem here is that it fill all the rows and I would rather if that piece of query couldn't be after the UNION ALL

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, sorry. I've added a complete query. The main advantage over `UNION ALL` is that the table has to be read only once.